# EXTRA with parcelable comes out NULL but without its fine

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, null, parcelable

I am getting a bit frustrated with an issue that I cannot seem to fully understand.

I have a listview with items and when I click them I want to pass an object (Parcelable) to a new activity. This is the code below:

```
lv_Entries.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent getItchesScreen = new Intent(Home.this, Itches.class);

            getItchesScreen.putExtra("i", 3);

            Entry e = entries.get(position);

            getItchesScreen.putExtra("entry", e);

            startActivity(getItchesScreen);
        }
    });
```

Now, I have the "i" extra there for debugging purposes. I was just sending "entry" and when I got the intent on the activity it didn't work. Code below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_itches);

    tv_date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_date);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

    entry = b.getParcelable("entry");

    tv_date.setText(entry.getDate());

    itches = entry.getItches();

    itchesAdapter = new ItchAdapter(this, itches);

    ListView lv_Itches = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_itches);

    lv_Itches.setAdapter(itchesAdapter);
}
```

So when I read my bundle there is nothing at all. No "entry" key and no "i" key (I debugged to read i using watch feature)

BUT! If I don't send "entry" and only send "i" and I debug to catch "i" I do get it!

I have no idea why sending entry is ruining things but I cannot find any answer. I debugged the object and it does find it though .get(position).

Hope anyone can give me any ideas, and sorry for any trouble.

*EDIT*

Below is the code for Entry:

```
public class Entry implements Parcelable{

private String date;
private ArrayList<Itch> itches;

public Entry(String date){
    this.date = date;
    itches = new ArrayList<Itch>();
}

// PARCELABLE
public Entry(Parcel source){
    date = source.readString();
    source.readTypedList(itches, Itch.CREATOR);
}

public void AddItch(Itch itch){
    itches.add(itch);
}

// get intensity average for the itches
public int IntensityAverage(){

    int intensity = 0;

    for(Itch i : itches){
        intensity += i.getIntensity();
    }

    return intensity/itches.size();
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public ArrayList<Itch> getItches() {
    return itches;
}

public void setItches(ArrayList<Itch> itches) {
    this.itches = itches;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(date);
    dest.writeTypedList(itches);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Entry> CREATOR =
    new Parcelable.Creator<Entry>() {
        public Entry createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Entry(source);
        }

        public Entry[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Entry[size];
        }
    };
```

}

Itch class is also Parceable. I am populating correctly (no crashes on Android at least) the ListView with it.

For convenience I place the code here aswell:

```
public class Itch implements Parcelable{

private String time;
private String local;
private int intensity;

public Itch(String time, String local, int intensity){
    this.time = time;
    this.local = local;
    this.intensity = intensity;
}

// PARCELABLE
public Itch(Parcel source){
    time = source.readString();
    local = source.readString();
    intensity = source.readInt();
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public String getLocal() {
    return local;
}

public void setLocal(String local) {
    this.local = local;
}

public int getIntensity() {
    return intensity;
}

public void setIntensity(int intensity) {
    this.intensity = intensity;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(time);
    dest.writeString(local);
    dest.writeInt(intensity);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Itch> CREATOR =
    new Parcelable.Creator<Itch>() {
        public Itch createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Itch(source);
        }

        public Itch[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Itch[size];
        }
    };
```

}

Comment: You never call b.getInt("i") there (you must have taken it out when not testing). If entry is null or parceled improperly you will run into issues.

Comment: How do I know if it is parceled improperly? Edit: Yes I do not have "i" there. I usually do that kind of testing through debugging "watch"

Comment: Did you write the entry parcel or is it an Android native Entry class?

Comment: It is mine. I wrote it. I cannot post the whole code (limit char) here but I can give you this bit:
@Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(date);
        dest.writeTypedList(itches);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Entry> CREATOR =
        new Parcelable.Creator<Entry>() {
            public Entry createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
                return new Entry(source);
            }

            public Entry[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Entry[size];
            }
        };

Comment: Could you post it so we can see if you might have made a possible mistake in parceling.

Comment: I will put it in my post.

Comment: Parcel looks good, I'm stumped. Will have to look into it some more.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) I really am not sure what is going on... It is really really weird.

Comment: Alright I found out the problem I will write it in the end of my post. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright so... What was the problem? Simple.

The reason why the parcelable always came out null was because a stupid error was occurring. Which error?

Well, okay so take a look at this piece of code:

```
entry = b.getParcelable("entry");
```

What is it saying? It is saying that entry will be equal to the parcelable "entry" key. But what does that really mean? Look at entry constructor.

```
// PARCELABLE
public Entry(Parcel source){
    date = source.readString();
    source.readTypedList(itches, Itch.CREATOR);
}
```

So when you say that entry is equals to a parcelable, then you will call this constructor in the Entry class that I have posted. But why is it wrong you might ask?

Well, so take a look. We're giving ArrayList itches to the method readTypeList. but... wait a second. If that is a constructor that means that we're building from 0... So... is itches initiated? No it is not! Because I was only initiating itches in the "normal" constructor!

```
public Entry(String date){
    this.date = date;
    itches = new ArrayList<Itch>();
}
```

So the solution is...

```
// PARCELABLE
public Entry(Parcel source){
    date = source.readString();

    //add this if condition!
    if (itches == null) {
        itches = new ArrayList<Itch>();
    }

    source.readTypedList(itches, Itch.CREATOR);
}
```

And thats it. That fixes our problem! :)

If other error occurs please be aware:
Make SURE that your key is correct. So check out for any typos in your getting extras.

```
entry = b.getParcelable("entyr");
```

as instead of

```
entry = b.getParcelable("entry");
```

And any other type of error like that.

That is not a good practive, you should have a variable that has the "entry" written on it so you never have this type of error mistakes. I have it in my code because I am fast-programming to build up a prototype :)

Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

have you tried doing this in `onCreate()`

```
Intent i = getIntent();
    if(i.hasExtra("entry")){
        entry = i.getParcelableExtra("entry");
    }else{
      Log.v("EXTRAS", "entry not found");
    }
```

Comment: How will that help me? Because that only states that if I don't have any key "entry" I don't do anything except log it. I always have an Entry. Hope I didn't sound harsh, sorry though.